# Svelte reactive statement not triggering, when variable updated asynchronously in another file

Tags: asynchronous, svelte

A reactive statement isn't triggering how I expect, in this toy example. I'm updating a variable `x` in a separate file, and I'd expect this update to trigger a reactive statement in my main app, but it doesn't. When I use the same logic inside my main app, for variable `y`, it does trigger the reactive statement. Why isn't the reactivity working the same for `x` as for `y`?

TestApp.svelte:

```js
<script>
import { x } from './test.mjs';

let y = "unset";

async function inity() {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100));
    console.log("inity timeout done");
    y = "set";
}
inity();

$: console.log("x:", x);
$: console.log("y:", y);

</script>

<p>Hello world</p>>
```

test.mjs:

```js
export let x = "unset";

async function initx() {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100));
    console.log("initx timeout done");
    x = "set";
}

initx();
```

The output I see at the console:

```
x: unset
y: unset
initx timeout done
inity timeout done
y: set
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reactivity is only analyzed within Svelte files. If you update values outside you have to use [stores](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store).

The Svelte code is compiled to include the necessary logic to call `$:` code on change, the JS is not touched and hence will not have any of the necessary logic. Stores have a built-in mechanism for signaling changes that Svelte can work with.